# Is that possible to upload and download files with jsf with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, primefaces

Is that possible to upload in my application files Pdf in location like C:/folders/pdfs/...
when I create a new component

and when I consult this component I can download his description  pdf

I'm using jsf2 and tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces has a [fileUpload component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadSingle.jsf). Using it, users can upload files (you can restrict to only allow PDF files). Once the file is uploaded, you can choose to do anything with it; store it in file system or in database or in an external drive such as Amazon S3.
To render pdf files in html you can use Primefaces [media component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf).

As for the pdf description, I don't know what you mean, but you can store in database title, description and some id of the pdf so you can find it later.

Comment: think you Damian for your cooperation :)

Comment: @FERESSS you are welcome. please mark the answer ask correct by clicking the tick if it was helpful